# Cannot send message to Azure IoT Hub to units with ":" in their device id

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am trying to send messages from my machine to a IoT-Hub. I am using the following code:

```
    message = Message('{{"temperature": 20,"humidity": 10}}')
    client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
    client.send_message(message)
```

This works when the deviceId in CONNECTION_STRING doesn't have colons in it.

```
CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=my-iot-hub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=E0:DC:A0:73:C6:C3;SharedAccessKey=password"


CONNECTION_STRING = "HostName=my-iot-hub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=my_device;SharedAccessKey=password"
```

The first connectionstring doesn't work. The process hangs when trying to send the message - but doesn't give me an error message. The second sends without any problems.

Is there some way to escape the colons?

Comment: I have duplicated this issue using the Python 3.7 and azure-iot-device (2.2.0), but using the REST, direct MQTT protocol or .Net SDK, the device id with colons is working well.

Comment: also, there is no problem when using Python 3.7 and *paho.mqtt* library when the device id contains colons, but in the *sas_token*, the colons are encoded using the *%3a* characters.

Comment: @Wobli are you still blocked? Can you check Roman's suggestion and use higher version of Python ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We confirmed this is a bug with url encoding. In the next release of [azure-iot-device](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python) (releases higher than 2.3.0), we will be adding a fix.

Thanks.